# Existence of operator

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I want to show that for $ s> \frac{1}{2} $ there is a bounded linear operator $ T: H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$ following the below steps:

- Consider that  $ u \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ and show that  $ \widehat{Tu}(\xi')=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat{u}(\xi', \xi_n) d{\xi_n}$.
- Show that $ (1+|\xi'|^2)^{s-\frac{1}{2}} |\widehat{Tu}(\xi')|^2 \leq \text{ constant } ||u||_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2 $.

Why do we show in that way that there is an operator as the desired one?

Let $ u \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Then $ \widehat{Tu}(\xi')=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} Tu(\xi') e^{-ix \xi' }d{x} $.

Why is this equal to $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat{u}(\xi', \xi_n) d{\xi_n} $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here the author probably meant that $T\mu$ is the restriction map
$$
T\mu(\xi_1,\cdots, \xi_{n})=\mu(\xi_{1},\cdots, \xi_{n-1},0)
$$
Now writing out explicitly we have
$$
\widehat{T\mu}(\xi')=\int\mu(\xi,0)e^{-i \xi\cdot \xi'}d\xi
$$
But recall that formally [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632950/explanation-of-this-integral/1632960#1632960) (for 1D functions)
$$
f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \widehat{f(\xi_{n}')}d\xi_{n}'=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int (\int f(x)e^{-x\cdot \xi'_{n}}dx)d\xi_{n}'
$$
Thus substitute $f(x)=\mu(\xi_{1},\cdots, \xi_{n-1},x)$ into above, we can re-write above as 
$$
\widehat{T\mu}(\xi')=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \mu(\xi_{1},\cdots,x)e^{-i(\xi,x)\cdot (\xi',\xi_{n}')}dx d\xi_{n}'d\xi, \xi=(\xi_1,\cdots ,\xi_{n-1}),\xi'=(\xi_1',\cdots ,\xi_{n-1}')
$$
which can be further simplified to be
$$
\widehat{T\mu}(\xi')=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int (\mu(\xi_{1},\cdots,x)e^{-i(\xi,x)\cdot (\xi',\xi_{n}')}dxd\xi )d\xi_{n}', \xi=(\xi_1,\cdots ,\xi_{n-1}),\xi'=(\xi_1',\cdots ,\xi_{n-1}')
$$
and you get the desired formula this way. There may be something off with the constants. The $\xi_{n}'$ at here corresponds to the $\xi_{n}$ in your notation. It feels somewhat odd to me that $(\xi',\xi_{n})$ should be conflated together.

The rest of the proof now should follow from Cauchy-Schwarz if you use inequality of the type 
$$
|\widehat{\mu(\xi',\xi'_{n})}d\xi_{n}'|^2\le \int |\widehat{\mu(\xi',\xi'_{n})}|^2\cdot (|\xi'|^2+|\xi'_{n}|^2)^{s}d\xi_{n}'*\int (|\xi'|^2+|\xi'_{n}|^{2})^{-s}d\xi_{n}'
$$
and choosing appropriate cut-off by assuming $|\xi'|>1$.

Comment: Substituting $f(x)=\mu(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_{n-1}, x)$ don't we get the following?

$$\widehat{T \mu}(\xi')=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mu(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_{n-1}, x) e^{-i (\xi_1, \dots, \xi_{n-1}) \xi'} d{\xi_n'}\right) d{\xi}$$

Or am I wrong?

Comment: There is an $e^{-ix\cdot \xi_{n}}$ term coming from the Fourier transform formula I give for $f(0)$. You need to incorporate it into your formula to match.

Comment: I suppose the confusion may be because I chose to use $dx$ for the inner dummy variable and the value for $f$ in general, which is stupid. To clear it up maybe you can use $dy$, $dz$ etc to denote the dummy variable in the inside. Then everything should be clear. It is really a matter of patience.

Comment: I retried it and I got the following:

$$$$

$$\widehat{T \mu}(\xi')=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mu(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_{n-1}, x) e^{-i x \xi_n'} dx d{\xi_n'} d{\xi}$$

Is this again wrong?

Comment: @Evinda: Where is the $e^{-i\xi\cdot \xi'}$ term now? Is it flying away?

Comment: @Evinda: So you need to incorporate the $e^{i\xi\cdot \xi'}$ and the $e^{ix\cdot \xi_{n}'}$ term together. Then you get the formula I give above. The multiple integral signs are supressed in my notation. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: So the power of the exponential should be $-i(x \xi_n'+ \xi \xi')$, right?

Comment: Also we have that $\widehat{\mu}(\xi', \xi_n)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mu(\xi', \xi_n) e^{-i x \xi_n} e^{-i \xi \xi'} dx d{\xi}$, right? $$$$

If so, then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat{\mu}(\xi', \xi_n) d{\xi_n}=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mu(\xi', \xi_n) e^{-ix \xi_n'} e^{-i \xi \xi'} dx d{\xi} d{\xi_n}$. Right?

$$$$

Comment: This isn't equal to $\widehat{T \mu}(\xi')$. I am confused now with the notation. So is $\widehat{T \mu}(\xi')$ equal to $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat{\mu}(\xi, x) d{\xi_n}$ ? Or do we have to change at more points of our proof the notation?

Comment: Your formula of the triple integral is right (except $\xi_{n}$ should really be $\xi_{n}'$ in my notation). By convention of pseudo-differential operators, extra integral signs are surpressed. Thus in your question you only saw on integral, and I only wrote out a double integral. But it should really be a triple integral. A hint for you is $e^{-i(x\cdot \xi_{n}'+\xi\cdot \xi')}=e^{-i(\xi,x)\cdot (\xi',\xi_{n})'}$. Thus you are essentially doing Fourier transform for $\mu(\xi,x)$ by integrating out $e^{-i(\xi,x)\cdot (\xi',\xi_{n}')}$.

Comment: You mean that all the $\xi_n$ should be replaced by $\xi_n'$ ? I will have to look at it again. Could you maybe also explain to me how you applied the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: @Evinda: I prefer to leave it as a hint. Otherwise I essentially finished your work for you! Yes, in my proof above I think $\xi_{n}'$ makes more sense, since $\xi'$ lives in the cotangent bundle, messing up the notation can be confusing.

Comment: Does it hold that $||\mu||_{H_s}=(2 \pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}} \left( (1+|\xi_n|^2)^s |\widehat{\mu}(\xi', \xi_n)|^2 d{\xi_n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ ? If so, then at this definition,  $\xi'=(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_{n-1})$. Or am I wrong? @Bombyxmori

Comment: If so, then we get that $$(1+|\xi'|^2)^{s-\frac{1}{2}} |\widehat{T \mu}(\xi')|^2 \leq (1+|\xi'|^2)^{s-\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (1+|\xi_n|^2)^{-s} d{\xi_n} ||u||_{H_s}$$

Right? If so, how can we show that $(1+|\xi'|^2)^{s-\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (1+|\xi_n|^2)^{-s} d{\xi_n}$ is bounded by a constant? @Bombyxmori

Comment: @Evinda: Sorry I am in China now and the internet connection is quite bad. To see how this follow from Cauchy-Schwartz, notice that if we assume $s>1/2$, then $\int (|\xi'|^2+|\xi_{n}'|^2)^{-m}d\xi_{n}=c|\xi'|^{-2s+1}$ for some $c$. You then insert this into the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality I given in the answer.

Comment: @Evinda: The key observation is that by introducing a cut-off when $|\xi'|>1$, so while you need $\int_{\xi'\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}}(1+|\xi'|^2)^{s-1/2}|\widehat{T\mu}(\xi')|^2<\infty$, since $|\xi'|^{s-t}\le |\xi'|^{s}$ you do not need to worry about the lower order terms at all. And everything is bounded by $C\int |\xi'|^{2m-1} (\int|\widehat{T\mu}(\xi',\xi'_{n})|)^2$, which is further bounded by the $H^{s}$ norm of the original function.