# Principal value of complex exponential

Tags: limits, complex-integration, cauchy-principal-value

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%5Bexp%28i*a*x%29*dx%5D+from+-inf+to+%2Binf) you can see that Cauchy's principle value ($PV$) of the complex exponential is zero, i.e.,

$$
PV\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{iax}dx\right] = 0
\tag1 $$

I'm trying to prove this a follows:

$$
PV\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{iax}dx\right] = \lim_{T\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{-T}^{+T} e^{iax}dx = \frac{1}{a} \lim_{T\rightarrow +\infty} \left[ \sin(T) - \sin(-T)\right] \tag2
$$

In principle, one would write $\sin(T) - \sin(-T) = 2\sin(T)$ and would realize that the limit does not exist so the only thing I can try to prove the result in Eq. (1) is to work out both sines separatedly and assume that

$$
\lim_{T\rightarrow +\infty} \sin(T) = \lim_{T\rightarrow +\infty}\sin(-T) \tag3
$$

so finally you arrive to Eq. (1). Nevertheless, this is not very convincing from my point of view because  RHS limit is undetermined as well as LHS, so you should not assume Eq. (3) is right. Then, what's the right approach?

Comment: "Principle value" is the value you give to the tenets you live by; "Principal value" is the main value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$e^{iax}=\cos(ax)+i\sin(ax)$$

So, the integral is equal to

$$I=2\int_0^\infty \cos ax\, dx + i \int_0^\infty \sin ax\, dx - i \int_0^\infty \sin ax\, dx$$

All three integrals are [Cesaro-summable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation#Ces%C3%A0ro_summability_of_an_integral):

$$\int_0^\infty \cos ax\, dx = 0$$

$$\int_0^\infty \sin ax\, dx = 1$$

So, we have

$$I=2\cdot0+i\cdot1-i\cdot1=0$$

Comment: So this Cesàro summable thing means to change $\int \cos(ax) dx$ by $\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} \int (1 + x/a)\cos(ax)dx$ and this last one for being zero in the limit when $a$ goes to infinity allows you to say that the orginal cosine integral is zero. But is this only valid for $PV$ or it can be extended in general?

Comment: @Vicky Cesaro summable basically means it has an average value as the integration limit goes to infinity. Cesaro values of integrals are widely used in tables of Fourier transforms, for instance. This is not the same as Cauchy principal value. If we did not know the Cesaro value of $\int_0^\infty \sin x dx$, we still could speculate that since sine is an odd function, its integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin x dx$ is zero. This would be principal value. But since we quite know the integrals on the both sides of zero, we can just subtract 1 from 1 and arrive to zero even more reliably.

Comment: Cesaro summation is more reliable than Cauchy principal value because in Cauchy principal value we in general have to approach infinity in the both directions at the same pace, while in Cesaro summation the pace of approach does not matter and the integrals can be found separately on the right and on the left of zero.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the integral in cosine is not zero unless you do it as I explained in my 1st comment. So my question is if you used that in order to say that the cosine integral is null, because per se $\int_0^\infty \cos (ax) dx \neq 0$

Comment: @Vicky yes, Cesaro sum (or any more powerful method, like Abel) of that integral is zero. Otherwise one cannot know the value of the integral in question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iax} \, dx=\delta(a)$$

which vanishes when $a\ne 0$.

Please also refer to [*post 1*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632950/explanation-of-this-integral/1632984#1632984) and [*post 2*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/421771/what-is-principal-value-in-delta-function-integral) for your further interests.

In *Wolfram* or *Mathematica*, may the machine assume the integrand is evaluable:

[image]

Comment: And why would the value 0 be the PV of the integral? Why to pick $a \neq 0$ to get the PV?

Comment: I've uploaded different *Mathematica* outputs for your reference.